# Cannot find name error - How to import definitions file from node_modules/@types in angular?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, p5.js, definitelytyped

So I have this [node_modules/@types file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtVIT.png) with definitions I need. However, I can't seem to import it into my js file.

I've done `npm install @types/p5` and added it to my tsconfig.json like:

```
"types": [
        "node",
        "p5"
     ],
```

but name is still not found.

My code is essentially this:

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
//imports p5.js

export class Box { 

  ...

  show(p5) {
    p5.rectMode(CENTER);
  {

  ...

}
```

CENTER needs to be defined but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CENTER` is inside your `p5` instance, because you've imported all from `@types/p5` as `p5`:

```
const p = new p5(...); // specify arguments for p5

show(p) {
  p.rectMode(p.CENTER); // p.CENTER returns 'center'
}
```

Comment: The types file is actually separate from the p5.js file. I have a node_modules/@types/p5 and a node_modules/p5.js. My import statement is importing just the p5.js.

Comment: @colemars your're right, but as you're using typescript, it gets all definition from `@types/p5`